# Replace 0 in df1 when there is a 1 in df2 in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have 2 dataframes with the same number of columns and rows. df1 is filled in with 0s and NAs and df2 has 1s and NAs. Wherever there is a 1 in df2, I would like it to also appear in df1 by replacing the 0 that is found in the same spot in df1. The actual dataframes have approx 5000 columns and 85 rows, so I am looking for a solution that I can easily run over the entire thing.

df1 looks like this:

```
       1    2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10    
stat1  NA   NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  0   0   0
stat2  0    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
stat3  0    0   0   0   0   0   NA  NA  NA  NA
stat4  NA   NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
stat5  NA   NA  NA  0   0   0   0   0   0   0
stat6  NA   NA  0   0   0   0   0   0   NA  NA
stat7  0    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
stat8  NA   NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
stat9  NA   NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
stat10 NA   NA  NA  NA  NA  0   0   0   0   0
```

df2 looks like this:

```
       1    2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10    
stat1  NA   NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  1
stat2  1    NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
stat3  NA   NA  NA  1   NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
stat4  NA   NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
stat5  NA   NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
stat6  NA   NA  NA  NA  1   NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
stat7  1    NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
stat8  NA   NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
stat9  NA   NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
stat10 NA   NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
```

To reiterate, where there are 0s in df1 and NAs in df2, I would like to keep the 0s. Where there are NAs in both df1 and df2 I would like to keep the NAs. Where there are 0s in df1 and 1s in df2, I would like to keep the 1s.

I would appreciate any help with this, as I am a very novice R user!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We create a logical matrix and then assign the values to 1 based on the index

```
i1 <- (df2 == 1 & !is.na(df2)) & (df1 == 0 & !is.na(df1))
df1[i1] <- 1
```